# How can I select Yes/No qestionID dynamically in weka j48 App

Tags: weka

I'm developing a Weka app like Akinator by using the j48 method.

Sample:
http://jbossews-vdoctor.rhcloud.com/doctor

The following is the app's table definition and sample data
qa means question id(Please refer the master which can be set by user) + answer(1:Yes, 2: I don't know, 3: No).
1 line per 1 question & answer.

---

**id,qa,class**

A,13,1

A,23,1

B,13,2

B,21,2

---

The point is to find a way to select the question which can maximize the entropy.
Currently this app is regarding first node id of decision tree as the best question.
And then it narrows down the options by this elimination way.

But the accuracy was too bad to run correctly so I'd like to improve it.
I noticed that the qa column was identified as numeric so it could not build the correct decision tree.

I am confused what I should do for improvement.  Dataset? Table definition? Logic?

Comment: Thank you for your support, Mr.Spencer. About Table Definition, Once I tried to set questions to each column but I'd like user to add questions dinamically for more suitable question. So I coul not set such a table definition because it column could be expanded infinitely.  About dataset, I understood. I'll prepare and ask people to gather such a data set.

Comment: About logic, my app is almost same as your opinion. But I think my elimination logic is too simple to improve accuracy. As additional solution I'm considering to give weighting to each question according to question's data volume. Could you give me more answer about table definition & logic.                   I have should to prepare the no decease as you said. Thank you for your propose.

Comment: About the dynamic nature of the questionnaire:  Perhaps you could periodically update your trained model to account for other questions as new attributes, but some questions should not have been in there like 'Are you under 20 years old', because you already have the age.  Perhaps the modeller can use new information from users and then decide whether a new attribute will help diagnose the disease or if common attributes can be merged.  Giving power to the users could add many other layers of problems for diagnosis.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you for advising me. Yes, some questions should not be outputted as you said. I'll modify SQL to remove them. I've changed qa column's definition from numeric to nominal and set the binary option to J48. But it did'n output decision tree as same as my assumption. I think it was caused by table definition so that I'm considering to re-map the temp table like you said last time. Actually, I don't have much know-how about weka so I'm happy if you review my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a broad question that you are asking, and without code or a clear understanding of the problem it is quite difficult to answer, but I'll give some tips for improvement:

**Table Definition**

What may have made more sense here is to have an attribute for each question, instead of using a single instance per question.  For Example, instead of id, qa and class, you could have A, B, C, D, E, F and Disease.  (I believe there were six questions, and naming each attribute would be recommended instead of A-F)

**Dataset**

You will need at least as many cases as there are diseases, if not more for defining multiple subsets of the problem space for the same disease.  There are likely cases where some questions are irrelevant or missing, and the model may need to handle such situations.

**Logic**

In such a case, you might be able to do the questionnaire by starting with the root node and asking questions until you reach the estimated class.  This way, you can ask from node to node until a class is reached.

I hope this helps in improving your existing model.

*NOTE:  I tried your questionnaire and answered No to all of your questions, and I strangely ended up with Trichomoniasis.  Perhaps there could be a 'No Disease' category for your training data also.*

Answer (score 0):

My nominal qa data is building such a decision tree by binary split.
actually this structure won't make sense because there is tree at only one side. When qa equal 23 it would be always '3' answer. It's irrational.

http://www.fastpic.jp/viewer.php?file=2693704973.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should first reformat your features to get all possible questions A,B,C,D... as binary features and your final answer (ie. what to guess) as target class if you want your tree to get a sequence of questions reaching to your answer. Your data will certainly be sparse (many questions without data/answer).

By the way, a binary tree is not the right ML structure and algorithm to build an Akinator like or 20Q/Guess-who. Please look some suggestions here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/akinator-com-and-naive-bayes-classifier

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I want user to add their questions as I replied so I cannot define the column per question id. (Database max qty of column is about 1600)

Comment: your tables shouldn't store data the same way as the dataset. Table could simply store: #Answer-ID, #Question-ID, #Question-Answer. But the dataset would fetch all questions related to the same answer.